# C# method resolution surprise when using a "generic handler builder"

Tags: c#, generics

Today I stumbled upon a problem, which I couldn't explain to myself. I was trying to build a "generic handler builder", to clean up repetitive code in my project. I thought this could be easily achieved with some generics and the power of `Action<T>`.

I came up with a similar solution like this (this is a simplified version to show the "problem"):

```cs
using System;

namespace GenericActionBuilder {
    public class FirstMessage { }
    public class MessageHandler {
        public void HandleMessage(object msg)
            => Console.WriteLine("Fallback object handler");
        public void HandleMessage(FirstMessage msg)
            => Console.WriteLine("FirstMessage handler");
    }
    class Program
    {
        public static Action<MessageType> BuildHandler<MessageType>() {
            Action<MessageType> handler = (msg) => {
                Console.WriteLine($"Called with Type={msg.GetType().Name}");

                var messageHandler = new MessageHandler();
                messageHandler.HandleMessage(msg);
            };

            return handler;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // This is the surprise
            var generatedHandler = BuildHandler<FirstMessage>();
            var msg = new FirstMessage();
            Console.WriteLine($"Calling generated handler with type={msg.GetType().Name}");
            generatedHandler(msg);

            // This gives the expected behavior
            var myHandler = new MessageHandler();
            myHandler.HandleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Calling generated handler with type=FirstMessage
Called with Type=FirstMessage
Fallback object handler
FirstMessage handler
```

Of course I would expect that, when I call `HandleMessage` with a `FirstMessage` object at hand, C# would pick the best matching overload: `HandleMessage(FirstMessage)`. This is what happens if you don't utilize the "generic handler builder".

And even inside the generated handler the type of the `msg` is still `FirstMessage`. But still the call `handler.HandleMessage(msg)` triggers the "fallback" method with the object signature.

Can anybody explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> C# would pick the best matching overload

Yes, but it will do it on compile time (not runtime) based on information about type, which C# compiler can obtain from code.

Your handler has a generic parameter, but this parameter is not limited by any condition, so, it can be any type: `FirstMessage`, `object` or even `Program` and etc, then knowing this, the compiler will select "the best matching overload", which obviously is `HandleMessage(object)` because it can accept any provided type. To quickly check it, you can create base class/interface (`Message`) for messages and limit generic parameter to something like: `where MessageType : Message` and provide appropriate methods in `MessageHandler` class and you will see that the compiler will select `HandleMessage(Message)` instead of `HandleMessage(object)`.

So, you can try to implement visitor (double dispatch) pattern to solve this problem (I assume that you have more message types).

Comment: Oh thats surprising to me: Using the generic parameter forces C# to do the method wire up at compile time? I did not knew this. But this would make it clear. :)

Comment: @ghandi It works in the same way with usual parameters. If you create just a method instead of action delegate like: `Handler(object msg) { messageHandler.HandleMessage(msg); }` it will select `HandleMessage(object)` even if you pass `FirstMessage` type, because which method to call is determined on compile time.

Comment: @ghandi - unless you're using `dynamic` or some other forms of late binding, overload resolution *always* happens at compile time, generics or not. The compiler emits a token that identifies the specific method it's selected.